# Error Installing MySQL server on windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I am trying to install MySQL server on windows 10 using MySQL installer. It Fails with below log. Tried all the fixes said but nothing is working out for me.

```
1: Action 20:30:52: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {29AEA9CC-3A6A-4F86-8A0E-AC8750F91B69} 
1: Action 20:30:52: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 20:30:52: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 20:30:52: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 20:30:52: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 20:30:52: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 20:30:52: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 20:30:52: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 20:30:52: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
1: Action 20:30:52: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: Action 20:30:53: SaveTargetDir. 
1: Action 20:30:53: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 20:30:53: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
1: Action 20:30:53: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 20:30:53: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
1: Updating component registration
1: Action 20:30:54: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
1: Action 20:30:54: SchedSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: Action 20:30:54: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
1: Action 20:30:54: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
1: Action 20:30:54: RemoveFiles. Removing files
1: Action 20:30:54: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
1: Action 20:30:54: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Folder: Creating folders
1: Action 20:30:54: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: File: Copying new files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
1: Action 20:30:55: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: Creating shortcuts
1: Action 20:30:55: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: Writing system registry values, Name: , Value: 
1: Action 20:30:55: InstallServices. Installing new services
1: Action 20:30:55: SchedSecureObjects. 
1: Action 20:30:55: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: 
1: Action 20:30:55: RegisterUser. Registering user
1: Action 20:30:55: RegisterProduct. Registering product
1: Registering product
1: Action 20:30:55: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
1: Feature: Publishing Product Features
1: Action 20:30:55: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
1: Action 20:30:55: InstallFinalize. 
1: Action 20:30:55: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 20:30:55: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysql\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\performance_schema\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\test\
1: Action 20:30:55: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: File: ibd2sdi.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5097472
1: File: innochecksum.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5061120
1: File: libeay32.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 2102272
1: File: libmecab.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 1839616
1: File: lz4_decompress.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4946432
1: File: my_print_defaults.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4955136
1: File: myisam_ftdump.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5217792
1: File: myisamchk.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5327872
1: File: myisamlog.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5177856
1: File: myisampack.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5239808
1: File: mysql.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5290496
1: File: mysql_config.pl,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 7392
1: File: mysql_config_editor.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4972544
1: File: mysql_secure_installation.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5178880
1: File: mysql_ssl_rsa_setup.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5004288
1: File: mysql_tzinfo_to_sql.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4900864
1: File: mysql_upgrade.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 11030016
1: File: mysqladmin.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5186560
1: File: mysqlbinlog.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5476352
1: File: mysqlcheck.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5198336
1: File: mysqld.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 45210624
1: File: mysqld_multi.pl,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 28045
1: File: mysqldump.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5259264
1: File: mysqldumpslow.pl,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 8071
1: File: mysqlimport.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5179904
1: File: mysqlpump.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5664256
1: File: mysqlshow.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5178368
1: File: mysqlslap.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5196288
1: File: perror.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5593600
1: File: resolveip.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4953600
1: File: ssleay32.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 356864
1: File: zlib_decompress.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4920832
1: File: ChangeLog,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\docs\,  Size: 22
1: File: INFO_SRC,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\docs\,  Size: 184
1: File: binary_log_types.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2886
1: File: errmsg.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 5294
1: File: my_command.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 4385
1: File: my_list.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2603
1: File: mysql.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 31305
1: File: client_plugin.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql\,  Size: 7295
1: File: mysql_com.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 34068
1: File: plugin_auth_common.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql\,  Size: 5546
1: File: mysql_time.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2996
1: File: udf_registration_types.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql\,  Size: 3848
1: File: mysql_version.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 1054
1: File: mysqld_error.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 193371
1: File: mysqlx_ername.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 4745
1: File: mysqlx_error.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2954
1: File: mysqlx_version.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 1861
1: File: applink.c,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\openssl\,  Size: 3176
1: File: libmysql.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 5164032
1: File: libmysql.lib,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 27066
1: File: char.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 262496
1: File: dicrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 693
1: File: left-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 55910
1: File: matrix.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 3463716
1: File: pos-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 1477
1: File: rewrite.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 6241
1: File: right-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 55910
1: File: sys.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 37779919
1: File: unk.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 5409
1: File: char.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 262496
1: File: dicrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 693
1: File: left-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 55910
1: File: matrix.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 3463716
1: File: pos-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 1477
1: File: rewrite.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 6241
1: File: right-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 55910
1: File: sys.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 37635899
1: File: unk.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 5409
1: File: char.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 262496
1: File: dicrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 693
1: File: left-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 55910
1: File: matrix.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 3463716
1: File: pos-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 1477
1: File: rewrite.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 6241
1: File: right-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 55910
1: File: sys.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 49199027
1: File: unk.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 5690
1: File: mecabrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\etc\,  Size: 1403
1: File: mysqlclient.lib,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 61569518
1: File: adt_null.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 24064
1: File: component_log_filter_dragnet.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 31744
1: File: component_log_sink_json.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 16384
1: File: component_log_sink_syseventlog.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 15360
1: File: component_log_sink_test.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 30720
1: File: component_validate_password.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 65536
1: File: connection_control.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 47104
1: File: group_replication.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 1070592
1: File: ha_example.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 28672
1: File: keyring_file.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 108544
1: File: keyring_udf.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 25088
1: File: libpluginmecab.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 30720
1: File: libtest_framework.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 11776
1: File: libtest_services.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 19456
1: File: libtest_services_threaded.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 20480
1: File: libtest_session_attach.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 49152
1: File: libtest_session_detach.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 32256
1: File: libtest_session_in_thd.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 22528
1: File: libtest_session_info.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 49664
1: File: libtest_sql_2_sessions.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 34304
1: File: libtest_sql_all_col_types.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 37888
1: File: libtest_sql_cmds_1.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 37888
1: File: libtest_sql_commit.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 39424
1: File: libtest_sql_complex.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 40960
1: File: libtest_sql_errors.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 36352
1: File: libtest_sql_lock.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 45056
1: File: libtest_sql_processlist.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 34816
1: File: libtest_sql_replication.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 37376
1: File: libtest_sql_shutdown.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 29184
1: File: libtest_sql_sqlmode.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 39424
1: File: libtest_sql_stmt.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 65024
1: File: libtest_sql_stored_procedures_functions.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 38912
1: File: libtest_sql_views_triggers.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 38400
1: File: libtest_x_sessions_deinit.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 22016
1: File: libtest_x_sessions_init.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 27136
1: File: locking_service.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 13312
1: File: mypluglib.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 13312
1: File: mysql_no_login.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 12288
1: File: rewrite_example.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 13312
1: File: rewriter.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 65536
1: File: semisync_master.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 75264
1: File: semisync_slave.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 29696
1: File: test_security_context.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 12800
1: File: test_services_plugin_registry.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 23040
1: File: test_udf_services.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 14848
1: File: validate_password.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 53760
1: File: version_token.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 62976
1: File: LICENSE,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\,  Size: 301518
1: File: README,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\,  Size: 687
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\bulgarian\,  Size: 258842
1: File: armscii8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5939
1: File: ascii.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5925
1: File: cp1250.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8654
1: File: cp1251.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8783
1: File: cp1256.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5982
1: File: cp1257.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 9315
1: File: cp850.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5919
1: File: cp852.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5941
1: File: cp866.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6026
1: File: dec8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6942
1: File: geostd8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5929
1: File: greek.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6141
1: File: hebrew.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5930
1: File: hp8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5915
1: File: Index.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 19495
1: File: keybcs2.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5942
1: File: koi8r.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5923
1: File: koi8u.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6945
1: File: latin1.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 10229
1: File: latin2.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 7651
1: File: latin5.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5928
1: File: latin7.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 7851
1: File: macce.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8460
1: File: macroman.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8471
1: File: README,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 1749
1: File: swe7.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6943
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\czech\,  Size: 259348
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\danish\,  Size: 259348
1: File: dictionary.txt,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 25575
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\dutch\,  Size: 260368
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\english\,  Size: 258589
1: File: errmsg-utf8.txt,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 826306
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\estonian\,  Size: 258853
1: File: fill_help_tables.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 1023732
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\french\,  Size: 259996
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\german\,  Size: 266283
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\greek\,  Size: 265380
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\hungarian\,  Size: 259230
1: File: innodb_memcached_config.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 3999
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\italian\,  Size: 260359
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\japanese\,  Size: 266035
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\korean\,  Size: 261629
1: File: mysql_sys_schema.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 289722
1: File: mysql_system_tables.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 109850
1: File: mysql_system_tables_data.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 5510155
1: File: mysql_system_users.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 2289
1: File: mysql_test_data_timezone.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 10830
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\norwegian\,  Size: 258659
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\norwegian-ny\,  Size: 258712
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\polish\,  Size: 259518
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\portuguese\,  Size: 261549
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\romanian\,  Size: 260301
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\russian\,  Size: 273927
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\serbian\,  Size: 260970
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\slovak\,  Size: 259115
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\spanish\,  Size: 260243
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\swedish\,  Size: 259442
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\ukrainian\,  Size: 268501
1: Action 20:31:00: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: icon.ico
1: Shortcut: Icon.MysqlCmdShell
1: Shortcut: rpxm3ds_|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client
1: Shortcut: 7ejegqmo|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode
1: Action 20:31:00: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Location, Value: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Version, Value: 8.0.12
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: DataLocation, Value: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FaceName, Value: Lucida Console
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FontWeight, Value: #400
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 20:31:00: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 20:31:00: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {29AEA9CC-3A6A-4F86-8A0E-AC8750F91B69} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.12' failed.
```

Comment: Just because you claim to not have found a solution doesn't mean its not a duplicate.

Comment: @dfundako can you show me the duplicate post which have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you select the server in the installer and you move it into the panel on the right, expand the list of sub-components and untick "Server Data Files".  This worked perfectly on my laptop without needing to uninstall / clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I was installing the latest community edition on a Win10 machine this past Sunday. First round gave me exactly same message at same spot. I did a fresh download and everything installed fine. (Would have simply commented, but don’t have 50 points yet)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i found for this is to manually install mysql server on windows 10 and then install the other components using mysql installer. I have installed it manually and everything is working fine. You can refer to the below video for how to install and configure mysql manually on windows 10.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P99dA0yGY8g